# \geqslant Undefined control sequence in Latex

Tags: latex

When I compile the following latex code:

```
\begin{align}   
f_{m}(x) = c_{1,m} \times I(x_{i}^{m} \geqslant t_{m} ) + c_{2,m} \times I(x_{i}^{m} <     t_{m} ),  
\end{align}
```

I always get an error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.  
<argument> ..._{1,m} \times I(x_{i}^{m} \geqslant   
                                              t_{m} ) + c_{2,m} \times I...  
l.124 \end{align}
```

When I replace \geqslant with >=, it is okay.

I already include the amsmath package. What would cause the problem?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: This should be placed on the latex section

Answer (score 27, accepted):

That command isn't defined in the amsmath package, but rather the amssymb package -- put `\usepackage{amssymb}` in your preamble and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks, Etaoin. Is it possible to find out the package given its command? Sometimes it is hard to find it by google.

Comment: Sadly, I don't know of any package reference that can be searched by command.  That would be incredibly useful.

Comment: Most symbols are given by package in 
http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf
http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html can be used also.